# Como usar um collapsible sem um id para o elemento-alvo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou implementando um bbcode de spoilers para um fórum phpbb, que usa o Bootstrap e jQuery no tema.

O código é esse:

```
<div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">SPOILER!</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">{TEXT}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estou com dúvidas, já que o código da bbcode será igual pra todo bloco de spoiler e por isso aparentemente não posso usar a id para o elemento `collapse1`, pois todo e qualquer spoiler no tópico usará essa mesma id.

A pergunta então é: como eu vou "acionar" um collapsable pane sem usar uma id?

Desde já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a estrutura do HTML não mudar, uma alternativa seria dar o collapse na próxima `div` com a class correspondente, algo como:

```
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {

  $(this)
    //Pega todos os elementos parent
    .parents()
    //Pega a próxima div com a class .panel-collapse.collapse
    .next('div.panel-collapse.collapse')
    //e faz o collapse
    .collapse();
});
```

Não é a melhor forma, mais se não tiver o id é uma alternativa.

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/52VtD/14057/).

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="panel panel-warning">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" onclick="$(this).parents().next('div.panel-collapse.collapse').collapse('toggle');">SPOILER!</a>
        </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">{SPOILER}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Segue [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/52VtD/14062/) da solução dos comentários :)

Comment: O pior é que eu precisaria de uma versão desse código em um onclick no `<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">SPOILER!</a>`, pois o phpbb só me permite usar um único trecho de código pra cada bbcode.
Ah, e se precisar mudar o HTML (colocando algum javascript como o que eu sugeri acima), pode mudar.

Comment: É quase isto! Pena a função de collapse apenas mostrar o elemento, ela não oculta de novo no próximo clique

Comment: É só passar o 'toggle' como argumento para o collapse, amanhã faço um fiddle :)

Comment: Valeu, irei aguardar ansiosamente!

A solução não ficará mesmo elegante, mas é a única forma do phpbb aceitar!

De qualquer forma, valeu mesmo pela ajuda!

Comment: @Vico, segue o [**exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/52VtD/14062/) com o toggle :)

Comment: Testado, adicionado e funcionando beleza no fórum! ([segue exemplo](http://chronomania.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=6&p=61#p61))

Marcada como aceita! Muito obrigado!